# Can't simulate values extreme enough in Monte Carlo

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo

I have a biological dataset of 576 genes of interest and their assigned functional categories. I also have the assigned functional categories for all of the genes in the genome of the species I am working with. This allows me to set up a weighted, random, draw where I can pick 576 genes/functional assignments from the genome and see what the distributions are for the various functional categories. I have repeated this 1 million times which seems like overkill; however, for one of my categories, I am currently unable to simulate a value as extreme as I have in the genes of interest.

To provide context, the functional category (let's go with "A") represents 14% of the genome and 28% of the genes of interest. The highest value I've simulated is 22.92% for category A, and the 97.5% confidence interval is at 17.19%. This is giving me trouble when I go to calculate the p-value as I am doing that empirically, i.e. (number of values simulated for A that exceed the value of A for the genes of interest)/(total number of simulations), so my p-value is just zero.

```
len([i for i in probs_dict["A"] if i > target_per])/total_sims
```

Is there a different way to calculate p-values here or to represent the high degree of over-representation?

Comment: Interesting question, although more suited to stats.stackexchange.com. That said, one approach to ensure that low-probability events are covered is so-called stratified sampling; a web search for that should turn up some resources. But I have to wonder what's the point of computing p-values. All your models are wrong, so a large enough sample (easy to come by in genomics) will yield a "significant" result. Maybe you need a different way to assess significance or importance or relevance or whatever is the real object of interest.

Comment: Agree that this is likely a better question for the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack exchange sites

Answer (score 0):

It might be appropriate to add a 1 to your numerator and nominator. See this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC379178/) for example. This prevents p = 0 from ever happening. So your p-value formulation would become:

```
(1 + len([i for i in probs_dict["A"] if i > target_per]))/(1 + total_sims)
```